# How To Use FFMPEG -filter_complex_script When Merging Multiple Videos With Different Resolution

Tags: ffmpeg

Here's the command I'm using when merging two videos with different resolution, It works well

```
$command = 'ffmpeg -i first.mp4 -i second.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale='.$originalDimensions.':force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad='.$originalDimensions.':-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v0]; [1:v]scale='.$originalDimensions.':force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad='.$originalDimensions.':-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v1]; 
  [v0][0:a][v1][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -movflags +faststart '.$dupSavePath.' 2>&1';
```

It works nice and the output has no issues.

But now I want to merge multiple videos using a list of files.

We can use `concat` command and provide the list.txt file having a path to all the other video files.

I was going through the documentation and found that it's possible by using -filter_complex_script but have no idea how to make it work

Here's the command I used so far but the output having audio sync errors

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i downloads/list.txt -acodec ac3_fixed -vcodec libx264 -s 720x480 -r 60 -strict experimental output.mp4 2>&1
```

I can use the filter-graph here but I want to do it using `concat` command because the number of input files may vary.

Comment: Crosspost of [How To Use FFMPEG -filter_complex_script When Merging Multiple Videos With Different Resolution](https://superuser.com/questions/1616857/how-to-use-ffmpeg-filter-complex-script-when-merging-multiple-videos-with-diffe)

Answer (score 0):

I did work on a project for this I used concat but sometimes audio lags and some audio change will also occur depending on the type of files. In documentation and in multiple websites it is suggested to use concat only if all the files are of the same format in video and audio types to Hope u got a clear idea now.
here is how u can make a txt file and store the filenames u want to add
Here is the code in python

```
file = open(File_name_Path,"w")
    file.close()

    file = open(File_name_Path,"w")
    file.write("file '"+Intro_Path +"' "+"\n")
    file.write("file '"+Video_Path+fileNamee +"' "+"\n")
    file.write("file '"+Extro_Path +"' "+"\n")
    file.close()

    os.system("ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i "+File_name_Path+" -c copy "+Final_Path+fileNamee)
```

In-text file

```
file 'path of 1st file'
file 'path of 2nd file'
```

Hope u got some idea with concat

Just a suggestion if ur not sure of the file types or audio types use the 1st method as u mentioned because concat method sometime frustrates by changing pitch of audio

Thank you